# Change neo4j browser title

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to change the default browser title for Neo4j?

We run multiple instances and the current browser title (userID@bolt://ip-address:port) is not very useful - we'd like to say stuff like userID@Neo4j-Dev, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not roll your own ?
The browser is a separate github project that can be found at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser (comes with build instructions), and I believe you are looking to modify the files underneath **src/browser/modules/DocTitle**.

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is not possible change the default title of Neo4j browser. But as a workaround (not very elegant, i know :) you can open the console of your browser and type:

```
document.title = "My custom title";
```

The browser title will be updated.

Comment: Thanks - I've done this, it doesn't seem to stick when I return to the page from a new browser window, but crediting you anyway, will explore the code base to see if this is a minor thing to add and contribute:)